# django: Take table name as input from user and show the content of the table from database

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am trying to implement form in django, where I will take input from user, e.g, its table name and then I want to show all the content on the webpage. So, far I tried below code.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .models import my_custom_sql
from django.core.exceptions import *

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'forms_spy/form.html')

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_id = request.POST.get('textfield', None)
        try:
           webpages_list = my_custom_sql.objects.get(name = search_id)
           data_list = {'access_record':webpages_list}
           return render(request,'forms_spy/index.html', context=data_list)
        except my_custom_sql.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("no such user")
    else:
        return render(request, 'forms_spy/form.html')
```

forms_spy/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
def my_custom_sql(TABLE):
    with connections["my_oracle"].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {};".format(TABLE))
        row = cursor.fetchall()

        return row
```

templates/forms_spy/form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/search">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="textfield">

<button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

urls.py under project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from forms_spy.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #url(r'^', include('livefleet.urls', namespace='livefleet')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^search/', search),
    url(r'^index/', index),
]
```

I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028895/very-simple-user-input-in-django). When I entered the value getting below error.

```
RuntimeError at /search

You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/search/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

Comment: add a slash (/) at the end of url in browser or postman.

Comment: Ever heard of SQL injections ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry not aware but will check.thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in `urls.py`

from

```
url(r'^search/', search),
```

to

```
url(r'^search/', search, name='search'),



<form method="POST" action="{% url 'search' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="textfield">

<button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

ur url is `search/` , so u need to put the same in the `form action`

Comment: its not working , opening the page index/search/ with same content as index/

Comment: tried , now error is coming in views.py file. line 15 - webpages_list = my_custom_sql.objects.get(name = search_id)

Comment: thats a different error related to the database query

Answer (score 0):

change urls to

```
path('search/', search)
```

slash character for dynamic route, example call in browser (`http://domain/search`) or (`http://domain/search/`) if you using both it's work.

templates

```
<form method="POST" action="/search/">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="textfield">

<button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```